# BCAA with B6 vs BCAA without B6

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients, supplement

Is there a big difference between branched chain amino acid (BCAA) supplements with vitamin B6 and without it and their benefits in post workout use for amateur bodybuilders with regular diet?

Thanks!

Comment: This is very unclear. Are you talking about food or supplementation? What is a "big difference"? Are we talking about a person with defficiency in either B6 or amino acids, and if there is a defficiency, is it caused by inappropriate diet, or by some pathological condition? Also what do you mean by "how", are you interested in the exact biochemistry of amino acids absorption in the gut, or something else?

Comment: Hi @rumtscho thanks for comment. I edited it. Is it clear now or you have more sugestions for edit?